# How does Java work with wildcard search patterns?

Tags: java

I have a problem with Java. There is a Web application which has search functionality running with Javascript and Java in the backend. We are only allowed to configure Java source code and not Javascript.

The problem is that there is an `ArrayList<UserDTO>`. Each `UserDTO` contains `Id`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, and `email`. When I type `*` in the search engine, the results of all the `List` appears. The problem is with the Email. If I search one Firstname or Lastname, there is no problem. When I search for one email nothing works. It only works if I search for something like this: f.e. the email is gchat@mail.com, and if I type `* gchat@mail *` I find it. If I type `.`, after that, nothing works. Also, if I don't type the `*`, nothing works. f.e. If I only type the email like this: `gchat@mail` nothing works.

The source code for this is:

```
public ResponseEntity<List<UserDTO>> search(@PathVariable("query") String query) {
        List<UserDTO> results = new ArrayList<>();

        if (query != null && !query.trim().isEmpty()) {
            for (UserDTO user : USERS) {
                String regExp = "^" + query.trim().replace("*", ".*") + "$";

                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regExp, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
                Matcher firstnameMatcher = pattern.matcher(user.getFirstName());
                Matcher lastnameMatcher = pattern.matcher(user.getLastName());
                Matcher emailMatcher = pattern.matcher(user.getEmail());


                if (firstnameMatcher.matches() || lastnameMatcher.matches() || emailMatcher.matches()) {
                    results.add(user);
                }
            }
        }
```

and the list is this kind:

```
private static final List<UserDTO> USERS = new ArrayList<>();

    static {
        USERS.add(new UserDTO("jpap", "John", "Papadopoulos", "jpap@mail.com", true, "EL", new HashSet<>()));
        USERS.add(new UserDTO("kpav", "Konstantinos", "Pavlopoulos", "kpav@mail.com", true, "EL", new HashSet<>()));
        USERS.add(new UserDTO("echar", "Eleni", "Charalampous", "echar@mail.com", true, "EL", new HashSet<>()));
        USERS.add(new UserDTO("gchat", "Georgia", "Chatzipavlou", "gchat@mail.com", true, "EL", new HashSet<>()));
        USERS.add(new UserDTO("avel", "Apostolos", "Velis", "avel@mail.com", true, "EL", new HashSet<>()));
        USERS.add(new UserDTO("sliol", "Sofia", "Lioliou", "sliol@mail.com", true, "EL", new HashSet<>()));
        USERS.add(new UserDTO("ipap", "Iordanis", "Papageorgiou", "ipap@mail.com", true, "EL", new HashSet<>()));
        USERS.add(new UserDTO("jter", "John", "Terzis", "jter@mail.com", true, "EL", new HashSet<>()));
        USERS.add(new UserDTO("mkar", "Maria", "Karatasou", "mkar@mail.com", true, "EL", new HashSet<>()));
        USERS.add(new UserDTO("gap", "George", "Apostolidis", "gap@mail.com", true, "EL", new HashSet<>()));
    }
```

Please will someone help me? I have tried such different types, but nothing works properly.

Comment: Use `find` instead of `matches`, and remove the `^$`. `^.$` will only match strings that are 1 character long.

Comment: You suggest to remove ^ and $ for nothing??? I dont understand exactly what you wrote...

Comment: `matches()` only returns true if the *whole* string matches (so the `^` and `$` are actually superfluous). If you want "name@mail" to match "name@mail.com" then you shouldn't use `matches()`; you should use `find()` instead (which will tell you if a part of the string matches) - and use it without `^` and `*`.

Comment: Thank you my friend. My problem is solved. The search is working.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly the '.' is getting used as a wildcard in regex. try adding a / before the . similar to the way that you replaced * with *.

Answer (score 0):

multiple issues:

1. By concatenating user input like this, the user can enter regular expressions and you'll then compile these regular expressions, and run them. This sounds great, but be aware its possible to construct regexps which can more or less crash the server (take a LOT of CPU and RAM), so you probably don't want that: You can solve that by using `Pattern.quote`. This also solves other issues where .* in the string doesn't mean what you'd think it means due to the rest of the string (for example because you're in the middle of an optional group or some such because the user put a question mark in their query). If you want users to be allowed to enter regexp, then take the entire string and don't mess with it by trying to replace '*' with '.*'. And if you don't want that, then quote the input.
2. You're using `^` as a prefix and `$` as a suffix which means the regex must match the ENTIRE input, so if I search for 'foo@bar', that does not FULLY match 'foo@bar.com', and thus, it won't work. The solution is to put an additional .* in there, at start and end.

Combining the two:

```
StringBuilder regexp = new StringBuilder("^");
for (String elem : query.trim().split("\\*")) regexp.append(".*").append(Pattern.quote(elem));
regexp.append(".*$");
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexp.toString(), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
```

Answer (score -3):

Looks like your problem is not in pattern, but in Spring REST.

See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-pathvariable-dot for details.